# Modded Minecraft server with the mods messed up

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I made a Modded Minecraft server (hosted on my Computer) and the only mod it has is Lord of the Rings.

However, it is like the mod isn't there, I can't spawn anything in on *Not Enough Items* and I can't place or use anything. I can see the items on the Inventory and Creative GUI but in the game its impossible.

I did try the mod on a single player world, which worked.

I followed multiple YouTube videos, I checked the Forge versions (1.7.10) (and all the Forge versions inside 1.7.10) they are all identical.

It's not a permission issue, and I am an OP. It's the client saying to the server that this doesn't exist so I'm deleting it, but, it does exist. and within that, I don't know why it is doing that.

Comment: Note: I host the server on my computer

Comment: Hi, Caleb.  We provide help here, on Arqade, so it can help more than just you.  To that end, I've removed your Skype contact details.  That wouldn't help us help everyone that might be running into this issue.  That said, we're going to need a whole lot more information before we can do so.

Comment: I'd try running a single player instance of the game, to see if it's something to do with the server configuration configuration. Also check to see that cheat mode is enabled and not locked (cheat mode is locked by default).

Comment: I did try on a single player world, it worked.

Comment: All right, in that case, make sure that you're an op on the server. This is starting to sound like a permissions issue, possibly

Comment: I followed multiple youtube videos, I checked the forge versions (1.7.10) (and all the forge versions inside 1.7.10) they are all identical. I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: It's not a permission issue, and I am a op. It's the client saying to the server that this doesn't exist so I'm deleting it, but, it does exist.

Comment: And within that, I don't know why it is doing that.

Comment: What doesn't exist?

Comment: I think what's going on is exactly as you say; the mod is not there on the server at all. Check the mods folder in the server folder and make sure the mod is there.

Comment: Do you have the mod installed on your client end?

Comment: @KeithM sounds like the opposite to me. The client clearly showing the items, but them never existing in the world itself means that the *server* doesn't know the mod.

Answer (score 3):

> It's the client saying to the server that this doesn't exist so I'm deleting it, but, it does exist. and within that, I don't know why it is doing that.

It's exactly the opposite. If the items show up in NEI and creative, but can not be put into the game world, that means that the *server* has no clue about the mod, but the client does.

Here's an illustration of what happens when you try to get a mod item:

> **CLIENT:** Hey, SERVER, I want to have [ITEM].
>   **SERVER:** [ITEM]? What are you talking about, CLIENT? There is no such thing as [ITEM]. I'll remove whatever it is that you think you are holding.

I suggest you re-install the forge server and the mods on it.

1. Go to the [Forge website](http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/index_1.7.10.html) and download the installer (*not* the universal `.jar`!).
2. Run the Forge installer and select "Install Server"
3. Go to the installation directory and run `forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-universal.jar`, set the `eula=true`, and then run it again.
4. Place all server-side mods into the newly created mods folder.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may have to many mods on your sever this can make your game act up a bit try removing a mod off that world and see if it works it worked for me.